# Java: Scanner cannot read .txt file

Tags: java, file

***SOLVED*** Sat down with my professor today for a solid 30 minutes before we figured to create the "Scanner fileInput" before the "try" line. IT WORKED. Hope this helps someone else.

after extensive research, I have not been able to find out why the scanner does not pic up "hurricane.txt" I have it saved as a .txt in the project. I am using NetBeans. Any help is appreciated!

```
    // Openning hurricane data file


try{
   System.out.println("Openning hurricane data file...");
   Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("hurricane.txt"));
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e){


     System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
       return;
   }
   System.out.println( "File opened successfully...");
   System.out.println( "Reading file..." );
```

This is the output I get:

```
run:
Openning hurricane data file...
FileNotFoundException: hurricane.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: I think you do not have your hurricane.txt on classpath. Try to add it on classpath

Comment: Post result of `System.out.println(new File("hurricane.txt").getAbsolutePath());` and see if you really have file in this location.

Comment: The only possible explanation to this would be that the name is not the same or the file is not in the proper directory. The answers below should help you out. Oh, and don't forget to close the stream after you're done with it. You might just want to use the Try-With-Resource statement that Java provides.

Comment: Impossible to see why your 'solution' worked. The file either opens or it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Either specify the full path or place the text file in the application's working directory, which you can print out as follows:

```
final String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("Current working directory: " + workingDir);
```

Then ensure the text file is in that specific directory, and that the file name and extension match.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. The mistake i made was that i created/added a file and i called it junkfile.txt. But because i did that, the name it had was junkfile.txt.txt because the .txt extension gets added automaticly, so referring to it as junkfile.txt obviously didnt work and i got a filenotfound exception which took me a while to figure out.

So maybe if you use `hurricane.txt.txt` it will work.

Edit: if you made a text file in the working directory of netbeans and called it hurricane.txt it will appear in the projects list as hurricane.txt.txt .

Comment: Sat down with my professor today for a solid 30 minutes before we figured to create the "Scanner fileInput" before the "try" line. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
File f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("hurricane.txt").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your txt file doesn't have weird characters like accentuations such as the Spanish `ñ`, that causes the scanner to simply not print anything.